# Rounded corners in IE using border radius

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I've made a site using this border radius code: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

I'm referencing to url(border-radius.htc) to make it work in IE but it is not.

Please help, thanks.

P.S. Here's the site so feel free to look at my css: http://portsmouth.fitfans.co.uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/). It is very easy and useful.

**edit:** if the curved-corner works similar to css3pie the path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.
So in your css you have to fix the path of your current `behavior:url(border-radius.htc);` to `behavior:url(themes/hull/css/border-radius.htc);`

Comment: Tried your suggestion to fixing the path and that didn't work and also the site is now on CSS3PIE and still not working.

Very confused.

Please see http://portsmouth.fitfans.co.uk to see it is running it. Does it work in your IE?

Thanks

Comment: @Tim I checked your site. You still don't use the correct paths. I downloaded the page on localhost and it works with following change. Copy the PIE.htc on the folder with your php files or change the path for PIE.htc relative to the HTML file being viewed.